# something wrong with my loop where array (String type) where each word is written, if not repeated in a loop, is written to a dynamic array

Tags: java, for-loop, break

```
    arr.add(mas[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<mas.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) {
            if(mas[i].equals(arr.get(j))||mas[i].equals("")){
                break;
            }
            arr.add(mas[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) { 
        System.out.print(arr.get(j)+";");
    }
```

[image]

i dont understand what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Add the value from *mas*, only if the *inner-loop* does not find a match.

```java
boolean b;
arr.add(mas[0]);
for(int i=1;i<mas.length;i++) {
    b = false;
    for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++)
        if(mas[i].equals(arr.get(j))||mas[i].equals("")){
            b = true;
            break;
        }
    if (!b) arr.add(mas[i]);
}
for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) {
    System.out.print(arr.get(j)+";");
}
```

Output

```
car;cycle;bomj;
```

Ideally, just use the *[List#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))* method.
And, utilize the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))* method to print the concatenated values.

```java
String s;
arr.add(mas[0]);
for(int i=1;i<mas.length;i++)
    if (!arr.contains(s = mas[i])) arr.add(s);
System.out.println(String.join(";", arr));
```

Output

```
car;cycle;bomj
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted good your problem, you should add the item in the list only after the second loop.

```
arr.add(mas[0]);
outer: for(int i=1;i<mas.length;i++) {
    if ("".equals(mas[i])) {
        continue;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) {
        if(mas[i].equals(arr.get(j))){
                break outer;
            }
        }
        arr.add(mas[i]);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) { 
        System.out.print(arr.get(j)+";");
    }
```

I have edited the answer adding a label on the outer loop named "outer" and made some minor changes to make it more readable.

Comment: i think my code is wrong, i want to make (.contains) but without (.contains)

Comment: and every new word in "String" will be (.add) once, if array see word again dont (.add)

Answer (score -1):

```
    arr.add(mas[0]);    
    int raz=0;
    for(String word : mas ) {
        raz=0;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.size();j++) {
            if(word.equals(arr.get(j))||word.equals("")){
                raz--;
                break;
            }
            raz++;
        }
        if(raz==arr.size()){
            arr.add(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).